# MongoDB deleted logs

Tags: mongodb, disk-space, logs

So I recently realized my /var directory was growing but couldn't find anything using **du**, then find out about **lsof** and found the following:

```
lsof -nP | grep '(deleted)'
mongod    23184 23205          mongodb    5w      REG              202,1 10765518018     284593 /var/log/mongodb.asd/mongod.log (deleted)
```

Quite a few lines of those, but I understand they won't just dissapear until the mongod process is restarted?

Anything I can do about it?

This is under Ubuntu 16.04 and MongoDB 3.6.13.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like somebody deleted the log file while it was used by the mongodb process. Deleting log files is such a manner is not a good idea as the process will keep it locked and that means the file will keep occupying space on the disk. Such deleted files entry in the `lsof` will disappear once the process that is locking it is restarted.

The best way to handle logs files is by using proper log rotation by utilities like `logrotate` which is available on almost all linux systems.

If you ever face a situation where the log file has grown too big and you want to free up space without restarting the service, the best way would be to truncate the file using - `cat /dev/null > /var/log/my_big_log_file.log` or just `echo "" > /var/log/my_big_log_file.log`. Just remember that, this is not a proper solution for handling log files and should be used as a temporary fix.